# toRadixString(int radix) produces weird results

Tags: dart

I'm attempting to solve the common problem of "Given `n` & `k`, produce the `k`-th lexicographical permutation of the numbers `[1,2,...n]`"

When `n > 9`, there can be some ambiguity in the string representation and it looks messy, so I'm attempting to use the `toRadixString` method to convert each number into `base n`.

This is the code that I have:

```
String getPermutationFactoradic(int n, int k){
  var factoradic = [for(int i = 1, j=k-1; i <= n; j=j~/i,i++) j%i].reversed.toList();
  var numbers = [for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) i];
  return [for(int i = 0; i < factoradic.length; i++) numbers.removeAt(factoradic[i])].map((int num) => num.toRadixString(n)).join(' ').toUpperCase();
}
```

As you can see on the last line, I am mapping each number to it's radix string with a radix of `n`.

But, when I run the code like so - `print('iterative -> ${getPermutationFactoradic(16, 1996)}');`

the output that I get is this:
`iterative -> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 C F E A D 10 B`

My question is, why is the value `10` coming back instead of `A`? Is there some peculiar happenings within the toRadixString method that I don't know about? I'm really confused how this is happening.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numbers start from one, not zero. You have `n` numbers from 1 through `n`, and `n.toRadixString(n)` is "10".

Comment: Ohhh, ok. The 10 is actually 16(in decimal), but converted to base 16. I guess I should change the radix to be (n+1) to get the result I'm looking for. Thanks so much for answering pretty much every Dart question on SO